# "At one time", "at some point" or "one time"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which sentence sounds the most natural?

> I injured my back so bad, that **at one time** I couldn't even walk.
>
> I injured my back so bad that **at some point** I couldn't even walk.
>
> I injured my back so bad that **one time** I couldn't even walk.

What I am trying to communicate is that on one occasion my back was so bad that I couldn't walk. If none of my sentences sounds natural, what would a native English speaker say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is fine; 'at one point' works also.

The second ('at some time' also fits) more usually works for the future - 'at some point I won't be able to walk'), as if it was in the past I would know precisely what that point was. But in informal speech it's OK.

The third means something else. It means I was unable to walk only once. This may be the message you are trying to convey, but the first two imply an open duration (it lasted for an afternoon, a day a week....). If it happened only once I'd expect a pretty short duration; but that's my expectation and not a grammar rule.

Incidentally, you didn't hurt your back 'so bad', you hurt it 'so badly'.